# How to set common id for rows based on a column data

Tags: postgresql

I have many urls in my table and now I have to set new column value for each row based on they url.

for instance I have column url with next domains:

```
http://domain1.com
http://domain1.com/aaaa
http://domain1.com/bbbb
http://domain1.com/aaaa/bbbb
http://domain2.com
http://domain2.com/aaaa
http://domain2.com/bbbb
http://domain2.com/aaaa/bbbb

http://domain3.com/aaaa
http://domain3.com/bbbb
http://domain4.com/aaaa/bbbb
```

I've written next query (and it works well):

```
update sites set common_id = (select r.id from sites r where r.url = substring(s.url, 'http.+com'));
```

but.... as you might notice, I don't have http://domain3.com and http://domain4.com (or they have or don't have "/" at the end), therefore rows with this domains don't have their common_id, because my sub query can't find the url.

I want to listen any idea how can I set common_id for rows based on their domain? Please any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious issue is that the high level domain does not exist. Just as obviously then it needs to be added. I gave a couple attempts to insert them with CTEs then perform the update. Unfortunately those attempts failed. I think it's related to the MVCC concept that a statement only sees the database status as it existed at the start of the statement. (Maybe someone else can figure that out, I don't know). However, the below extracts where the high level domain that don't exist and inserts them. Run your query afterward to complete the process.

```
-- identify missing high level domains
with gsites as
        (select distinct on(url) 
                substring(url, 'http.+com') url 
           from sites
        )
-- insert the missing high level domains       
insert into sites(url)
       select url
         from gsites g
        where not exists (select null
                            from sites s1
                           where s1.url = g.url
                         ) ; 

--- update missing common_id 
update sites s 
   set common_id = 
       (select r.id 
          from sites r 
         where r.url = substring(s.url, 'http.+com')
       ) 
where common_id is null;
```

If this is to be a recurring issue you can wrap both above statements into the SQL function.

```
create or replace function establish_common_id()
  returns void
  language sql
as $$
>>> Insert above SQL statements here 
$$;
```